# Javascript Condition Statement Calling

Tags: javascript

How can I call function `CheckColour()` which performs checking of the "details" of the table? The if-else statement in `CheckColour()` will return the background colour of the element to "blue" when "details" is "M", else return pink (for the "F"). When I try to call the function as shown in the code I show, it won't work.

**JavaScript Code:**

```
//table      
var table = [
"Lyn", "22", "F", 1, 1,
"May", "32", "F", 18, 1,
"Sam", "27", "F", 1, 2,
"Sham", "23", "F", 2, 2,
"Hrs", "22", "M", 13, 2
];

// function calling starts here..

            for ( var i = 0; i < table.length; i += 5 ) {

                var element = document.createElement( 'div' );
                element.className = 'element';

                var number = document.createElement( 'div' );
                number.className = 'number';
                number.textContent = (i/5) + 1;
                element.appendChild( number );

                var symbol = document.createElement( 'div' );
                symbol.className = 'symbol';
                symbol.textContent = table[ i ];
                element.appendChild( symbol );

                var details = document.createElement( 'div' );
                details.className = 'details';
                details.innerHTML = table[ i + 1 ] + '<br>' + table[ i + 2 ];
                element.appendChild( details );
                element.CheckColour(details);  /*help me check this */

                /*CheckColour function, help me check this too if there is any error*/
                function CheckColour()
                {
                  var element, number, symbol, details;

                  if(details == "M")
                  element.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,191,255,0)';
                  else
                  element.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(255,105,180,0)';
                }
```

Comment: You're redefining all of your variables within the function so their values are `undefined` which is clearly != `'M'`. On top of that *"it doesnt't works"* is not a very good problem description.

Comment: nothing is being passed into the function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is not a method for `element`, so you should not call it on `element`. Instead pass `element` to the function as well.

Also, `details` is a DOM element, so it cannot be equal to `"M"`. Possibly you want to compare `table[i+2]` with `"M"`.

You could do it like this:

```
CheckColour(element, table[i+2]);

function CheckColour(element, details) {
    element.style.backgroundColor = 
        details == "M" ? 'rgba(0,191,255,0)' : 'rgba(255,105,180,0)';
}
```

This uses the [ternary operator (`? ... :`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) as an alternative to an `if ... else` statement, because both blocks of the `if` perform an assignment to the same property.

Make sure to move the `function` definition out of the loop. It only needs to be defined once.

Comment: Hm, it still don't change colour according to the details. Maybe it somehow related to the css.  Btw, thanks for your precious suggestion.

Comment: I don't know what you want to do, but in your code `details` is a DOM element. That obviously can never be equal to a string `'M'`. Maybe you want to check `table[i+2]` instead of `details`? Then pass that to the function: `CheckColour(element, table[i+2])`.

Comment: I did it yesterday, jst a minor correction in condition part, and it works. thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

What about extracting the function out and provide appropriate variables to it to perform the action.

```
function CheckColour(element, details) {
    if(details == "M")
    element.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,191,255,0)';
     else
    element.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(255,105,180,0)';
  }

//table      
var table = [
"Lyn", "22", "F", 1, 1,
"May", "32", "F", 18, 1,
"Sam", "27", "F", 1, 2,
"Sham", "23", "F", 2, 2,
"Hrs", "22", "M", 13, 2
];

// function calling starts here..

            for ( var i = 0; i < table.length; i += 5 ) {

                var element = document.createElement( 'div' );
                element.className = 'element';

                var number = document.createElement( 'div' );
                number.className = 'number';
                number.textContent = (i/5) + 1;
                element.appendChild( number );

                var symbol = document.createElement( 'div' );
                symbol.className = 'symbol';
                symbol.textContent = table[ i ];
                element.appendChild( symbol );

                var details = document.createElement( 'div' );
                details.className = 'details';
                details.innerHTML = table[ i + 1 ] + '<br>' + table[ i + 2 ];
                element.appendChild( details );

                // element.CheckColour(details);  /*help me check this */
                CheckColour(element, details);
                /*CheckColour function, help me check this too if there is any error*/


                var object = new THREE.CSS3DObject( element );
                object.position.x = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000;
                object.position.y = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000;
                object.position.z = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000;
                scene.add( object );

                objects.push( object );

                //

                var object = new THREE.Object3D();
                object.position.x = ( table[ i + 3 ] * 140 ) - 1330;
                object.position.y = - ( table[ i + 4 ] * 180 ) + 990;

                targets.table.push( object );

            }
```